# Selenium module issue

Tags: python, selenium

im trying to disable popup on the webiste

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('button.cmp-button_button.cmp-intro_acceptAll').click()
```

Unfortunately,I got this error

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

How can i repair that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is happening because your are calling `.click()` on the result of `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector`, which returns a `List` of `WebElement`. The error is telling you that you cannot click on a List, which is valid. You can fix this in a few different ways:

```
# only find a single element and click
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.cmp-button_button.cmp-intro_acceptAll').click()
```

or

```
# click the first element
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('button.cmp-button_button.cmp-intro_acceptAll')[0].click()
```

This can also be fixed by refining your selector to something more specific, that only retrieves one element, so you don't have to worry about lists or indexing at all. But in order to do this, we will need to see some HTML from the page you are trying to automate.

Comment: @witt32 If this answer helped solve your problem, feel free to mark this post as the accepted answer to your question, so other users can see that it was helpful for you.